# Nativescript Angular unable to load images from assets folder

Tags: image, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am unable to load an image localy and display it on the screen.

I have a file structure like this

```
src/
  - app/
      - assets/
             image.jpg
             header.jpg
             logo.svg
      - app.module.ts
```

so I have tried:

attempts:

```
<Image src="~src/app/assets/image.jpg" stretch="none"></Image>
----
<Image src="~/app/assets/image.jpg" stretch="none"></Image>
----
<Image src="~app/assets/image.jpg" stretch="none"></Image>
----
<Image src="~/assets/image.jpg" stretch="none"></Image>
----
<Image src="~assets/image.jpg" stretch="none"></Image>
```

none of them works.

the terminal is showing this error:

`JS: Error in reading bitmap - java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/assets/image.jpg (No such file or directory)`

Comment: try src="~/app/app/assets/image.jpg"

Answer (score 1):

As of **Nov 10 2020**. I was able to fix it using this solution from this Github issue [Nativescript-Angular Issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2280#issuecomment-720158368)

what fixed it for me is I moved the **assets/** folder inside **src/** folder.

structure like this:

```
src/
  - app/
      - app.module.ts
  - assets/
         image.jpg
         header.jpg
         logo.svg
```

and then in html:

```
<Image src="~/assets/image.jpg"></Image>
```